# Disable focus for background layout

Tags: android, layout, focusable

I show a settings box by clicking on a button. I use this code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="be.mforgetngroup.radioplayer.MainMenuFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main_menu_buttons">
</LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/settings_box"
        style="@style/settings_box">
        <LinearLayout style="@style/settings">
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/settings"
                style="@style/settings_title" />
            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end">
                <RadioButton
                    android:text="@string/dark_theme"
                    style="@style/settings_options" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:text="@string/light_theme"
                    style="@style/settings_options"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/settings_button"
        style="@style/settings_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

There is buttons in "main_menu_buttons". I want to disable all items of the screen except the settings box if this one is visible. Now, the focus can go from the settings box to the buttons of the main_menu. I don't want that.
Is there a way to do that without disable each item one by one ?

Here is the code to show/hide the settings box

```
                View settingsBox = getView().findViewById(R.id.settings_box);
                if(settingsBox.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                    settingsBox.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_in));
                    settingsBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else{
                    settingsBox.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_out));
                    settingsBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the Settings box in a match parent view and when I show the settings box setOnClickListener of that view to do nothing that will stop any click below it.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/stop_clicks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/settings_box"
    style="@style/settings_box"
    centerInParent="true">
    <LinearLayout style="@style/settings">
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/settings"
            style="@style/settings_title" />
        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end">
            <RadioButton
                android:text="@string/dark_theme"
                style="@style/settings_options" />
            <RadioButton
                android:text="@string/light_theme"
                style="@style/settings_options"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and

```
       View settingsBox = getView().findViewById(R.id.settings_box);
       View stopClicks = getView().findViewById(R.id.stop_clicks);
            if(settingsBox.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                settingsBox.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_in));
                settingsBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
stopClicks.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
stopClicks.setOnClickListener(v -> null);
            }
            else{
                settingsBox.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_out));
                settingsBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
stopClicks.setVisibility(View.GONE);
stopClicks.setOnClickListener(null);
            }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my app is use on a TV so I don't have any click, just a remote control so I use focus and not click. Thanks

Comment: Brilliant idea!!